# How to send data from a service class to a Fragment using Live data:Android

Tags: android, mqtt, viewmodel, iot, android-livedata

I'm using the MQTT service to receive some sensor data readings  in my app

```
class MqttService : Service() {
     val mqttLive_data = MqttLiveData()
    override fun onMessageReceived(topic: String?, message: MqttMessage?) {
      
      var data = MqttModel()
      data.setMqttData(MqttMessage)
      
      //This does not update the live data model 
      mqttLive_data.postValue(data)
    }}
```

When I receive the MQTT message, I want to pass it to my Fragment. I've tried to use LiveData + ViewModel, but unfortunately, postValue() does not update the view model.

```
class MqttLiveData: ViewModel() {

private var _mqttData = MutableLiveData<MqttModel>()

val mqttLiveData:LiveData<MqttModel>
get() = _mqttData}


class FragmentItemLiveData(subcategoryId: String?, deviceType_: String?) : Fragment(){ 
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_live_data, container, false)
        mqttViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MqttLiveData::class.java)
        mqttViewModel.mqttLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { mqttData ->
            
        })
        return root
    }}
```

Comment: `MqttLiveData` is `ViewModel` you can not create a new one in Service and pretend that it will be same as Fragment's . This is a clear use case of Bounded Service. Get the Binder set a listener and get the callback .

Comment: You should use _Bounded Service_ in this case.